# How do I keep track of the balance on a bank account?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, counter

I am going to create a program that keeps track of the balance on a bank account. The program shall use a loop that continues until the user choses to exit by answering ***no*** to the question ***Do you want to continue?***.

In the loop the user shall be asked to enter an amount (positive for deposit and negative for withdraw). The amount shall be added/subtracted from an account balance variable. All deposits/withdraws shall be saved as a *history* so that we can print it later. When the user choses to exit the loop the current account balance together with the account history (from the array/ArrayList) shall be printed.

***Now, I want to use an array with ten slots for the history feature.***

***My question is how can I keep track of the all deposit, withdraw and current account balance (using an array with ten slots for the history feature) so that I can print it out while the user exits the program?***

My code:

BankApp class:

```
package bankapp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        askingUser au = new askingUser();

        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\nYou have 100 SEK by default in your account.");

        while (true) {

            au.userInput();

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Answer by Yes or No.");
            String yesOrNo = input.next();

            if (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                au.userInput();

            } else if (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                System.out.println("History: ");

                //print out the transaction history
                System.exit(0);

            } else {

                System.out.println("Invalid character input.");

            }

        }

    }
}
```

askingUser class:

```
package bankapp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class askingUser {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double initialBal = 100;

    public void userInput() {
        System.out.println("Enter your amount: (+ve for deposit & -ve for withdraw)");
        double inputAmount = input.nextDouble();

        if (inputAmount >= 0) {

            double newPosAm = initialBal + inputAmount;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is: " + newPosAm + " SEK");

        } else {

            double newNegAm = initialBal + inputAmount;
            System.out.println("Your current balace is: " + newNegAm + " SEK");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: An array would be a bad idea, since you need to "remember" which index is the newest one and then have to parse that array in reverse order. It's might be better to use a `ArrayList` and insert the newest entries on index `0`. Then you can remove entries with index numbers > 10.

Comment: Good idea, that's what I was thinking. ArrayList could be better.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if anyone stumbles upon it they should know that due to precision issues, doubles and floats should not be used for currency. Fixed point numbers should be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an array, you have to keep track of the number of elements stored inside and resize the array when necessary. The easiest way would be to keep the history as strings in [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). You would add one message to that list per transaction:

```
ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<String>();

void addToHistory(String transaction) {
    history.add(transaction);
}

void printHistory() {
    for(String s : history) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

addToHistory("Withdrawal: 100 SEK" );
addToHistory("Deposit: 200 SEK" );
printHistory();
```

Comment: It's still unclear. Because the user will enter amount several times. And each the the amount is entered should be added to the arrayList. That means the history must be added automatically and dynamically. That was the main issue. So could you please modify please your code to show me the right track. I am not forcing you to do it, it's up to you. Thank you.

Comment: You just have to call `addToHistory` on every transaction. Just like you print the balance to screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need a **queue** to do that. However, for a **simple, fast and primitive implementation** you can:

- Define an object called `Transaction`(`deposit - double, withdraw - double, current account balance - double`)
- Add a `List` of `Transaction`s into `askingUser` class as an **attribute**. I strongly recommend **renaming the class name** to `AskingUser` to make it seen as object.
- At each operation add a new `Transaction` to end of the `List` you just added.
- At exit, print out the last -say- 10 elements of the `List`; you can reach it through `askingUser` object. You can also define a function in `askingUser` class to print out the last 10 elements, if you make the function work according to selected number of elements, you can add number of `Transaction`s to the function's inputs.